# How do I drop a row from this data frame?

Tags: pandas

```
ID  Address                   City          State     Country   Name           Employees
0   1   3666 21st St       San Francisco    CA 94114    USA    Madeira              8
1   2   735 Dolores St     San Francisco    CA 94119    USA    Bready Shop         15
2   3   332 Hill St        San Francisco         Cal    USA    Super River         25
3   4   3995 23rd St       San Francisco    CA 94114    USA    Ben's Shop          10
4   5   1056 Sanchez St    San Francisco    California  USA    Sanchez             12
5   6   551 Alvarado St    San Francisco    CA 94114    USA    Richvalley          20
```

```py
df=df.drop(['3666 21st St'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I am using this code and still, it's showing an error stating that :

```
KeyError: "['3666 21st St'] not found in axis"
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: It's unrelated to the proper way to solve this problem, but you cannot assign **and** use `inplace=True` simultaneously; it's one or the other. `df = df(some_inplace_operation)` guarantees that df is then `None` as that's the return for inplace operations.

Answer (score 1):

The `drop` method only works on the *index* or *column names*. There are 2 ways to do what you want:

1. Make the `Address` column the index, then `drop` the value(s) you want to drop. You should use `axis=0` for this, and *not* `axis=1`. The default is `axis=0`. Do not use `inplace=True` if you are assigning the output.
2. Use a Boolean filter instead of `drop`.

The 1st method is preferred if the `Address` values are all distinct. The index of a data frame is effectively a sequence of row labels, so it doesn't make much sense to have duplicate row labels:

```py
df.set_index('Address', inplace=True)
df.drop(['3666 21st St'], inplace=True)
```

The 2nd method is therefore preferred if the `Address` column is *not* distinct:

```py
is_bad_address = df['Address'] == '3666 21st St'

# Alternative if you have multiple bad addresses:
# is_bad_address = df['Address'].isin(['366 21st St'])

df = df.loc[~is_bad_address]
```

You need to consult the Pandas documentation for the correct usage of the `axis=` and `inplace=` keyword arguments. You are using both of them incorrectly. **DO NOT COPY AND PASTE CODE WITHOUT UNDERSTANDING HOW IT WORKS.**

Comment: Before asking this question I referred to other people's questions related to the same topic and they had told that adding axis and inplace would remove the error. So I tried that but that did not work as well for me later I tried using the indexing method using "iloc" which worked.@shadowtalker

Comment: @KarthikK you were told incorrectly. Do not copy and paste code without understanding how it works.

Comment: what do you mean by bad address ..sorry did not get that. Like do you mean I should name it better or I should use a different function? @shadowtalker                                           and thanks for your help

Comment: "bad" = "what you want to remove"